# swift - how to get JSON response from server

Tags: ios, json, swift, swift4, urlsession

I'm sending this data to a server and I would like it to respond. Tried this code but it doesn't work.

```
    let parameters = [ "imie" : (imie), "nazwisko" : (nazwisko), "telefon" : (telefon), "adres" : (adres), "miasto" : (miasto), "kod" : (kod), /*"powiat" : (powiat), "wojewodztwo" : (wojewodztwo),*/ "opis" : (selectedvalue)   ]


    let url = URL(string: "http://www.hetman.pl/post1.php")!
    var request = URLRequest(url: url)
    request.httpMethod = "POST"
    request.setValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Accept")
    request.setValue("application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
    request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
    request.setBodyContent(parameters)

    let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request as URLRequest) { data, response, error in
        if error != nil{
            return
        }

        do{
            let t = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: .allowFragments) as? [String:AnyObject]
            print(t as? String)
        } catch{
            print("Error 43 -> \(error)")
        }


    }
```

Request is correct and server is processing data properly, but response gives me this error:

```
Error 43 -> Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3840 "Invalid value around character 3." UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=Invalid value around character 3.}
```

So the question is, how do I get the data back from server?

Comment: Can you show printed `t` - your JSON?

Comment: `print(t as? String)` That's supposed to work? I don't think so. You should get "Cast from '[String : AnyObject]' to unrelated type 'String' always fails" (also don't use `AnyObject` in Swift 4). Instead, `let responseString = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8); print("responseString: \(responseString)")`. Also `request as URLRequest` should be useless.

Comment: can you share the postman collection?

Comment: may be your json is not in the correct format. verify it through postman.

Answer (score 0):

Why there is to content type?

```
// code 3840, data.length = 1 byte, so empty and no error
```

1. `request.setValue("application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")`
2. `request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")`

Remove first content-type header field and try with only:

```
request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
```

Answer (score 0):

Please check if response from this url is JSON only. You might be getting XML or string response.

Try below line if you are getting ***String*** response :

```
let stringResponse = String(data: data!, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8) as String!
```

Try below line if you are getting ***XML*** response :

```
let xmlDictionary = try XMLSerialization.xmlObject(with: data!) as? [String: Any]
```